# Border color not changing using Tailwind CSS and Next.js

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

When I pass `borderColor` as a prop, it doesn't work. However, it works fine when hard-coded.

```js
export const SecondaryButton = ({
  borderColor = "secondary",
  text = "Button",
  to,
  hoverBg = "primary",
  hoverText = "white",
  hoverBorder = "primary",
  textColor = "white",
}) => {
  const cn = `hover:border-${hoverBorder} hover:bg-${hoverBg} hover:text-${hoverText} block px-[3rem] py-[1rem] rounded-md text-${textColor} font-medium border-2 mt-[2rem] transition-colors ease-in-out duration-300 border-${borderColor}`;
  return (
    <>
      <button
        className={cn}
        >
        {text}
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

**Parent Component**

```js
const Right = () => (
  <div className="right px-[10rem] w-1/2">
    <h2 className="text-5xl custom-border-bottom">ABOUT US</h2>
    <p className="mt-[3rem] text-2xl">
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
    
    <SecondaryButton text="Learn More" borderColor="blue" textColor="gray" />
  </div>
);
```

As you can see below, the border is still light gray instead of blue:

[image]

Below is the image after putting hard-coded value:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Found the documentation regarding naming conventions

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names

Answer (score 1):

The CSS file generated by Tailwind will only include classes that it recognizes when it scans your code, which means that dynamically generated classes (e.g. `border-${hoverBorder}`) will not be included. See: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names

You could fix this by passing the full utility-class names to your component so that they are included in the CSS:

```js
<SecondaryButton text="Learn More" borderColor="border-blue-500" textColor="text-gray" />
```

And then apply them directly in your component:

```js
const cn = `${textColor} ${borderColor} ...`;
```

Another solution, if you have a small number of possible color values, would be to add them to Tailwind's safelist in `tailwind.config.js`. This will force Tailwind to include the proper utility-classes, whether or not it finds them in your code.

```js
module.exports = {
  safelist: [
    'border-blue-500',
    'text-white',
    'text-gray',
  ]
}
```

More on safelisting: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes

Answer (score -2):

TailwindCSS doesn't allow you to generate classes dynamically. So when you use the following to generate the class…

```
const cn = `hover:border-${hoverBorder} hover:bg-${hoverBg} hover:text-${hoverText} block px-[3rem] py-[1rem] rounded-md text-${textColor} font-medium border-2 mt-[2rem] transition-colors ease-in-out duration-300 border-${borderColor}`;
```

…TailwindCSS will not pick that up as a valid TailwindCSS class and therefore will not produce the necessary CSS.

Try to replace the value of `cn` with this

```
const cn = "hover:border-" +hoverBorder+ " hover:bg-" +hoverBg+ "hover:text-" +hoverText+ " block px-[3rem] py-[1rem] rounded-md text-" +textColor+ " font-medium border-2 mt-[2rem] transition-colors ease-in-out duration-300 border-"+ borderColor;
```

Comment: Didn't work.
I can see the class while doing inspect, but when i click on file, i cannot find class of .border-blue.
When i hardcode blue, it works

Comment: this is because in tailwind css`border-blue` class does not exist . You have to give className like `border-blue-400`. Refer here https://tailwindcss.com/docs/border-color

Comment: This won't work, because you are still building the Tailwind classes dynamically. This will prevent the Tailwind build from finding the classes and including them in the CSS file.